# Eight month infant not sitting on her own in full control

Tags: infant, development

Is it normal for an Eight month infant female to not yet control her body and fall over if no support is given? She can sit for few seconds(10-20) but it seems she does not like sitting much and just falls over purposely. And hence cant leave her in the sitting position without supervision. She gets stiff and prefers to stand with full support rather then sit with the partial support.

Comment: Sounds a bit delayed, but not too bad. If you let her spend plenty of time on her tummy, she'll develop the muscle strength to be able to sit up.

Comment: I had an 11 month old that couldn't sit on his own but was walking... and couldn't crawl.

Comment: A visit to the ped confirmed early stage calcium deficiency to be treated with calcitrol, vit d3 drops etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know for sure: every child progresses through physical development differently. Our daughter didn't walk until 15 months; some kids are walking unassisted at 9 months. Some kids skip cruising altogether and go from crawling to walking. There are many factors in development, and most of them are not "problems", just differences.

To help you feel less worried, I recommend you call/visit your pediatrician, and tell them your concern. They're used to these sorts of questions, and see hundreds of kids each year. It'll help.

Comment: i hope its not defieciency

Comment: Ali, the odds are extremely high that your child is doing perfectly normal. Call the pediatrician.

Comment: A visit to the ped confirmed early stage calcium deficiency to be treated with calcitrol, vit d3 drops etc